# rails s not working when I enter it on terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, terminal

when I try to input rails s on my terminal this is what i get

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[Simple Form] Simple Form is not configured in the application and will use the default values. Use `rails generate simple_form:install` to generate the Simple Form configuration.
Exiting
/Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Julians-MacBook:forum julian$
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: Add your `routes.rb` file here. PS. Reading the stacktrace usually helps identifying problems.

Comment: And this key line from the stacktrace is how @Uzbekjon knew to mention that "/Users/julian/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load': /Users/julian/Desktop/forum/config/routes.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)"

Comment: thank you so much @Uzbekjon for bring up routes.rb to my attention. I forgot to end the command after member do
    get "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    get "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"

Comment: @msergeant thank you too for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you forgot an `end` keyword in your `routes.rb` file.